# Possible bugs with InverseFunction in version 11.2

Tags: equation-solving, functions

See these two examples
[image]

```
InverseFunction[HarmonicNumber][10]
N[%]
InverseFunction[HarmonicNumber][10.]

InverseFunction[Fibonacci][89]
N[%]
InverseFunction[Fibonacci][89.]
```

Different types of numbers (`Integer` and `Reals`) return a different result, is this a bug? I am using  windows 10 64 bit version 1703.

Comment: V 11.1.1 (on Win 10, 64-bit) performs a lot better: It only returns a `Root` object for the first case, which is simplified to the correct result by `N`

Comment: The problem is that the results that are returned are not technically wrong - `Fibonacci[-12.649...4]` is really equal to `89`. You can use `FunctionExpand@Fibonacci@x` to get an idea of why this works

Comment: @Mathe172 then can we call it a "regression"?